# Couldn't send string variable in struct through tcp

Tags: c#, winforms

I have struct on server and client:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct ObserverStrings
{
   [FieldOffset(0)]
   public int id;
   [FieldOffset(8)]
   public string info;
}
```

Through id I understand which info was received.

On client I send info with id = -3

```
ObserverStrings observerStrings = new ObserverStrings {
    id = -3,
    info = "This is info"
};
byte[] data = WriteStruct(observerStrings);
stream.Write(dota, 0, data.Length);
```

On server I receive it

```
ObserverStrings os = ReadStruct<ObserverStrings>(RecievedData, 0, bytes); 

public T ReadStruct<T>(byte[] buffer, int index, int count)
{
     byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[count];
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         tempBuffer[i] = buffer[index + i];
     }
     GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(tempBuffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
     T temp = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(T));
     handle.Free();
     return temp;
}
```

After this I'm getting "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt" or id = -3 and just some strings which really far away from that I sent.

Also I tried:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Measure, 8, bytes - 8));
string[] mesInfo = builder.ToString();
```

But also get id = -3 and some strings which really far away from that I sent.

Comment: You are using plumbing that was meant to interop with unmanaged code.  Default marshaling of System.String is to char*, a **pointer** to a zero-terminated 8-bit character string.  The way that C code expects it.  That pointer is never valid in another process, AVE is the expected outcome.  There is no perfect way to do this, you need [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr)] and must pick a maximum size for the string.  Best to not do this at all and rely on BinaryReader/Writer or the many alternative serialization libraries.

Comment: Change `ObserverStrings` in a class object, serialize it as XML (very simple, one line of code) or JSON, send that, deserialize to the same class object on the other side.

Comment: Check the number of bytes received and make sure it is the same number of bytes transmitted.